# Is it possible to initialize an object with the literal notation if there are dependencies among its members?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, object-literal

Suppose I have an object like this

```
a = {b = function() { return 1 }, c: 2, f: 3}
a.z = a.b()
```

Is there a way to write it in a single assignment of object literal notation? Similar to:

```
a = {b: function() { return 1 }, c: 2, f: 3, z: this.b()}
```

Obviously this won't work because `this` is still bound to the scope that is defining the object, not the object itself. `a.b()` doesn't work either because `a` is not defined yet.

I'm actually using CoffeeScript but I'm pretty sure that if there is a clever way of doing this in plain JavaScript, it's going to look shorter and more "functional" in CoffeeScript as well.

Comment: The only way I can think of is declaring the function outside the object. The fancy thing about JavaScript is how it assigns the `this` scope. That object that is to the left of the dot is effectively `this` within the function. So you can still conveniently use `this.c` if you need to. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWS45/) Since you do not have any "private" properties of your object, I'd personally stick with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take advantage of JS's leaky assignments to memorize the value of the property to another variable from within the object literal:

```
a = { b: b = function() { return 1 }, c: 2, f: 3, z: b() };
```

note that as shown, b is a global, so you should likely use something like "var b, a=" (rest of code as shown) to prevent leakage.